# How to get for loop into list comprehension?

Tags: python, for-loop, list-comprehension

My for loop goes as follows:

```
Object_id_lst = []

for id_tic in ticket_df['ID']:
    get_object_id = api_client.crm.tickets.associations_api.get_all(ticket_id=id_tic, to_object_type='contacts')
    if len(get_object_id.results) > 0:
        Object_id_lst.append(get_object_id.results[0].to_object_id)
    else:
        object_id = 0
        Object_id_lst.append(object_id)
```

I wanted to see if there was a way to get this into a list comprehension for faster computing time.

Comment: Why do you think a list comprehension will make it faster?

Comment: My general knowledge of list comprehension shows that they are quicker, but my knowledge could perceive me otherwise

Comment: What type is `get_object_id.results`?

Comment: For append operations in a for loop, list comprehension should be faster.

Comment: The bottleneck here is probably the call to `api_client.crm.tickets.associations_api.get_all()` and the way you construct the list is negligible.

Comment: What Python implementation and version are you using?

Comment: They're not necessarily quicker (at least, not just by virtue of being list comprehensions, but due to the lack of attribute lookups like `Object_id_lst.append` that you can eliminate from your `for` loop as well).

Comment: [Premature optimization is the root of all evil](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization). Do whatever you feel is most natural and readable, and optimize it if it becomes a performance bottleneck.

Comment: You should use a profiler to determine if the calls to `append()` are the slowest part of the loop.

Comment: @KellyBundy I am running 3.10.6 in VSC code, also the object is a list

Comment: Does the `get_all` function require keyword arguments or is `get_all(id_tic, 'contacts')` equivalent?

Comment: Since you only use at most one, is there a `get_one` function that might be faster?

Comment: @KellyBundy the get_all does need arguments `get_all(id_tic, 'contacts')`

Comment: The main thing missing to turn this into a *readable* list comprehension is a better way to handle empty lists than `get_object_id.results[0].to_object_id if get_object_id.results else 0`.

Comment: Not sure what you're saying, since you now show positional arguments and say "need". So is that way equivalent?

Comment: @chepner Comprehension still looks faster to me, even after optimizations: [130 ms vs 200 ms](https://www.mycompiler.io/view/JrIHhOwgNPR). Or can you make the loop as fast as the comp? Making that long expression readable is easy, just access `.results` before. Should be done for speed anyway. See my list comp version.

Comment: "for faster computing time." that is not what list comprehensions are for. They do have *some minor* optimizations, but it is still essentially a for-loop with append. As the work you do inside the body of the look increases, these advantages become meaningless

Comment: @KellyBundy there is a minor bytecode hack that you cannot really reproduce in Python code, but that is practically meaningless in pretty much any non-vacuous circumstance. So look how much the time difference narrows if you do something like `(str(x) + "foo"` instead of just `x`: https://www.mycompiler.io/view/7kAQ04d2AgH

Comment: @MichaelCao no, not really. List comprehensions do not exist for speed optimizations, they are implemented as for-loops with `.append`ing to a list underneath the hood

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Yes, I know it's minor, but it's still there.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think making it a list comprehension will help much, other optimizations might help more. I did both:

```
Object_id_lst = [
    results[0].to_object_id if results else 0
    for get_all in [api_client.crm.tickets.associations_api.get_all]
    for id_tic in ticket_df['ID']
    for results in [get_all(ticket_id=id_tic, to_object_type='contacts').results]
]
```

My optimizations (besides making it a comprehension):

- Fetching the `get_all` function only once instead of every time.
- Fetching `.results` only once instead of twice.
- Checking truth of `results` instead of calling `len` on it, comparing with `0`, and checking the truth of the comparison result.

Another alternative (should be in a function, not global, so you get faster variables):

```
Object_id_lst = []
append = Object_id_lst.append
get_all = api_client.crm.tickets.associations_api.get_all
for id_tic in ticket_df['ID']:
    for result in get_all(ticket_id=id_tic, to_object_type='contacts').results:
        append(result.to_object_id)
        break
    else:
        append(0)
```

Comment: Your list comprehension reduce the computing tome bu 5 minutes, so thank you for that.

Comment: @Astro_raf What was the time before? And can you tell the time with my alternative solution on the bottom? I can't tell which one should be faster, both have their own advantages.

Answer (score 1):

It's not pretty, but you can do it by using the walrus operator to assign `get_object_id` inside the list comprehension, so you can test its length and also use it in the value part of the comprehension.

```
Object_id_list = [
    get_object_id.results[0].to_object_id 
        if len((get_object_id := api_client.crm.tickets.associations_api.get_all(ticket_id=id_tic, to_object_type='contacts')).results) > 0 
        else 0
    for id_tic in ticket_df['ID']]
```

More realistically, I would move all that conditional code into a function, and map that.

```
def object_id(id_tic):
    get_object_id = api_client.crm.tickets.associations_api.get_all(ticket_id=id_tic, to_object_type='contacts')
    if len(get_object_id.results) > 0:
        return get_object_id.results[0].to_object_id
    else:
        return 0

Object_id_list = list(map(object_id, ticket_df['ID']))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Object_id_list = [api_client.crm.tickets.associations_api.get_all(ticket_id=id_tic, to_object_type='contacts').results[0].to_object_id 
                  if len(api_client.crm.tickets.associations_api.get_all(ticket_id=id_tic, to_object_type='contacts')) > 0
                  else 0
                  for id_tic in ticket_df['ID']]
```

Comment: This will almost certainly be twice as slow, since it calls `api_client.crm.tickets.associations_api.get_all()` twice during each iteration. So if the goal was to speed things up, this won't work.

Comment: You are missing a square bracket at the end, just fyi